# Explicitly set ROWNUM in column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to split what was a large table update into multiple inserts into working tables. One of the queries needs uses the row number in it.  On an INSERT in oracle, can I explicitly add the `ROWNUM` as an explicit column?  This is a working table ultimately used in a reporting operation with a nasty partion over clause and having a true row number is helpful.

```
create table MY_TABLE(KEY number,SOMEVAL varchar2(30),EXPLICIT_ROW_NUMBER NUMBER);

    INSERT /*+PARALLEL(AUTO) */ INTO MY_TABLE(KEY,SOMEVAL,EXPLICIT_ROW_NUMBER) (
    SELECT /*+PARALLEL(AUTO) */ KEY,SOMEVAL,ROWNUM
    FROM PREVIOUS_VERSION_OF_MY_TABLE
);
```

where `PREVIOUS_VERSION_OF_MY_TABLE` has both a `KEY` and `SOMEVAL` fields.

I'd like it to number the rows in the order that the inner select statement does it.  So, the first row in the select, had it been explicitly run, would have a ROWNUM of 1, etc.  I don't want it reversed, etc.

The table above has over 80MM records. Originally I used an UPDATE, and when I ran it, I got some ORA error saying that I ran out of UNDO space.  I do not have the exact error message at this point anymore.

I'm trying to accomplish the same thing with multiple working tables that I would have done with one or more updates.  Apparently it is either hard, impossible, etc to add UNDO space, for this query (our company DB team says), without making me a DBA, or spending about $100 on a hard drive and attaching it to the instance.  So I need to write a harder query to get around this limitation.  The goal is to have a session id and timestamps within that session, but for each timestamp within a session (except the last timestamp), show the next session.  The original query is included below:

```
    update sc_hub_session_activity schat
    set session_time_stamp_rank = (
        select /*+parallel(AUTO) */ order_number 
        from (
            select /*+parallel(AUTO) */ schat_all.explicit_row_number as explicit_row_number,row_number() over (partition by schat_all.session_key order by schat_all.session_key,schat_all.time_stamp) as order_number
            from sc_hub_session_activity schat_all
            where schat_all.session_key=schat.session_key
        ) schat_all_group
        where schat.explicit_row_number = schat_all_group.explicit_row_number
    );
    commit;

    update sc_hub_session_activity schat
    set session_next_time_stamp = (
        select /*+parallel(AUTO) */ time_stamp
        from sc_hub_session_activity schat2
        where (schat2.session_time_stamp_rank = schat.session_time_stamp_rank+1) and (schat2.session_key = schat.session_key)
    );
    commit;
```

Comment: "split what was a large table update into multiple inserts into working tables" sounds strange - what is the problem with your statement, it should work as intended. However, the order of `ROWNUM` will be random, so I don't see any purpose for it.

Comment: Ordering is not guaranteed until you specify an `ORDER BY` statement. Even this select statement may give different ordering depending on various of reasons, meaning that the row number is quite pointless here. So you'd better describe the problem you trying to solve rather than working on this imaginary solution.

Comment: "*and having a true row number*" - there is no such thing as a "true" row number. Rows in a relation table are not sorted. The only thing you can sort (and thus get a "true" row number) is the result of a _query_ and that **requires** an `order by` to get a guaranteed sort order

Comment: Although you can use the `row_number()` analytic function (which isn't "nasty" by any means; I'm not sure why you think analytic functions could be?) to label rows according to your desired ordering.